# How do cellular waste products enter arterial blood?

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation, kidney

I recently learned that blood in renal arteries contains waste materials, which is filtered via nephrons in the kidneys.

My question is, how are these waste materials getting into the arterial blood? I believe arterial blood is pure and devoid of waste (since all the waste from cells and tissues must enter veins).

Comment: there's numerous "waste" products that are continuously produced via metabolism - like urea and ammonium - these are continuously excreted in the urine or eliminated in the feces - they are present in the entire circulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arterial blood isn't "pure". It is simply in one part of a complex circuit which carries varying degrees of oxygen, nutrients, and waste products, etc., to varyious parts of the circuit.

> ...how are these waste materials getting into the arterial blood?

The most simple and direct (but teleological) answer to this is that toxins *need to get into arterial blood to ever get to the kidneys to be filtered*. The arteries carry blood to every part of the body, detoxifying organs included. Veins carry blood away. If there were no waste products in arterial blood, the kidney would be superfluous.

Waste is produced in all tissue. Blood carries oxygen and nutrients to the tissue (where *some* of it is used), and via the venous side (all over the body) blood carries the waste products (as well as unused oxygen and nutrients) away toward the heart. The blood carrying waste products collects in increasingly larger veins until it is dumped into the right side of the heart and pumped into the lungs, where a major waste product (CO<sub>2</sub>) is *partially* removed. Things that need to be removed by the kidney are all still there. Blood carrying these toxic products is dumped into the left side of the heart, and thus enter the arterial blood supply. The kidney then can remove waste products partially or completely when it reaches them.

Comment: Good grief. Now that I have 10K, I can see how unnecessary my answer was. :-(

Comment: That was helpful.